# posting text to foursquare from android application

Tags: android

I want to post message/text to foursquare. Please provide me some code or document which sends 
message/text to foursquare .I have got example from  https://developer.foursquare.com/ but this example only authenticate and even documentation does not provide any explanation of posting text/ or any other things.

thank you

Comment: Sorry for that .Actually I was not aware for such accep rate .